# Mathematica struggles to solve system of trigonometric equations?

Tags: equation-solving, simplifying-expressions

As explained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4842239/if-r-sin-psi-r-sin-phi-and-r-cos-psi-ar-cos-phi-what-are-r-a), I'm trying to solve $$-ar \cos \phi = R \cos \psi \\
r \sin \phi = R \sin \psi$$ for $R, \psi$ in terms of $r, \phi$.

I believe the correct solution is $$R = r \sqrt{a^2 \cos^2 \phi + \sin^2 \phi}\\\psi = \arctan(\frac {-1} a \tan \phi)$$ but cannot get Mathematica to produce anything like that.

Instead, I get solutions like
[image]

where it doesn't even solve for $\psi$!

Using `Reduce` gives a solution for $\psi$, but it's very different than what I'd expect:

[image]

I'm very new to Mathematica, so if I'm using it incorrectly, please let me know.  Also: I can assume that e.g. $\phi$ is in the first quadrant and that $\psi$ is the simplest angle that works (I don't need every solution in $\mathbb R$).

Also: While my ideal would be to have Mathematica produce a simple solution, if it could verify or disprove my solution, that would also meet my needs.

---

## Code below

```
eq1 = -a r Cos[\[Phi]]==R Cos[\[Psi]] 
eq2 = r  Sin[\[Phi]] == R  Sin [\[Psi]] 
Solve[eq1 && eq1, {\[Psi], R}]
Solve[eq1 && eq2, {\[Psi], R}]
Reduce[eq1 && eq2, {\[Psi], R}]
```

Comment: Please post your code as formatted text, not as images, so people can copy / paste it into their own notebook and run it. It should be easy to back-substitute your solution into your equations to see if it's correct though. See e.g. `ReplaceAll` in the docuemntation.

Comment: You have `eq1 && eq1` while it should be `eq1 && eq2`.

Comment: @corey979 Thanks! Fixing that, I still don't get something I can parse.

Comment: What version of *Mathematica* and platform are you using?  For Windows 10 and *Mathematica* versions 13.3.1.0 and 14.0.0.0, `Solve` works fine.

Comment: @JimB I'm using Mathematica Cloud.  Can you post the code and results you get on the version you mentioned?

Comment: `Solve[eq1 && eq2, {\[Psi], R}] // FullSimplify` results in `{R -> -((r Sqrt[1 + a^2 + (-1 + a^2) Cos[2 \[Phi]]])/Sqrt[2]), \[Psi] -> ConditionalExpression[ArcTan[(a Cos[\[Phi]])/Sqrt[
     a^2 Cos[\[Phi]]^2 + Sin[\[Phi]]^2], -(Sin[\[Phi]]/Sqrt[a^2 Cos[\[Phi]]^2 + Sin[\[Phi]]^2])] + 2 \[Pi] ConditionalExpression[1, \[Placeholder]], ConditionalExpression[1, \[Placeholder]] \[Element] Integers]}` for one solution and

Comment: `{R -> (r Sqrt[1 + a^2 + (-1 + a^2) Cos[2 \[Phi]]])/Sqrt[2], \[Psi] -> ConditionalExpression[
   ArcTan[-((a Cos[\[Phi]])/Sqrt[a^2 Cos[\[Phi]]^2 + Sin[\[Phi]]^2]), Sin[\[Phi]]/Sqrt[a^2 Cos[\[Phi]]^2 + Sin[\[Phi]]^2]] + 2 \[Pi] ConditionalExpression[1, \[Placeholder]],  ConditionalExpression[1, \[Placeholder]] \[Element] Integers]}` for the second solution.

Comment: @JimB Thank you.  I was not aware of `FullSimplify`.  Using it, i get results similar to what you posted.  Is there a way I can have Mathematica check if my expected solution (at the beginning of the OP) is correct?

Comment: A standard form for an equation is many times in the eye of the beholder.  I think your proposed solution matches one of the *Mathematica* solutions (at least for $R$).  Try taking the difference in the solutions for $R$ and $\psi$ and see if applying `FullSimplify` results in 0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a bit of code that gives the solution closer to the form we would prefer.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
$Version

simplify = First[Simplify[#, C[1] ∈ Integers]] &;

eqns = -a r Cos[ϕ] == R Cos[ψ] && r Sin[ϕ] == R Sin[ψ];

soln = Solve[eqns, {ψ, R}];

prefer = {R -> Sqrt[R^2 /. soln // simplify],
   ψ -> ArcTan[Tan[ψ] /. soln // simplify]}
```

In Wolfram Cloud the code evaluated to
[image]

Sometimes we must give Mathematica some guidance.  What worked this time to get closer to the preferred form was to simplify $R^2$ and $\tan(\psi)$ then use the `Sqrt` and the `ArcTan` to create the desired solution form.

In this case I defined a `simplify` function that provides an assumption (`C[1] ∈ Integers`) to the plain `Simplify` and then returns only the `First` expression in the list returned by `Simplify`.

**Edits in response to comment:**

**To verify the hand calc for $R$:**
If we only want to verify that our hand calc is correct, we will look at `soln` and think maybe something is wrong.  But since we are confident in both the hand calc and `soln` we will try to manipulate `soln`.  One manipulation is to look at $R^2$ by evaluating `R^2 /. soln`.  We see that MMA did not multiply it out, so we apply `Simplify`.  We find that `Simplify[R^2 /. soln]` gives us the some expression as our hand calc, so we're done!

**To verify the hand calc for $\psi$:**
Similarly for $\psi$ we want to manipulate the MMA `soln` to obtain something we can compare to our hand calc.  `soln` contains `ArcTan`, so we use `Tan` to get a simpler expression.  We evaluate `Tan[ ψ /. soln]` and find that it requires further simplification, so we next evaluate `Simplify[ Tan[ ψ /. soln] ]`.  The result matches our hand calc for $\tan \psi$, so we're through.

**Explanation of `prefer`:**
`Solve` gives us the solution(s) as a list of rules that we use with `ReplaceAll`, the `/.` operator in further calculation.  The variable `prefer` is a new set of rules, similar to `soln`, but in the preferred form.  `prefer` is defined by using same manipulations we used to verify the hand calculation.  That is, we start with `R^2 /. soln`, then simplify and take the square root to get an expression for $R$. `prefer` could be used in place of `soln` in further calculation.

**Explanation of `simplify`:**
We do the same thing for $\psi$, but `soln` contains a `ConditionalExpression`, which is not unusual with inverse trig functions.  We can tell MMA to simplify assuming the constant is an integer, which effectively eliminates the condition.

Comment: Wow.  Can you explain (or direct me to a resource)  how the `prefer` line works? I don't follow the `R -> Sqrt[R^2 /. soln // simplify]` expression.  How would I use it, e.g., if I wanted to see if $\psi = \arctan (\tan \phi / a)$ (without the minus sign) also works?

Answer (score 4):

A Weierstrass substitution `ψ -> 2 ArcTan[uψ]`  is the way to solve these equations:

```
eqn = {-a r Cos[ϕ] == R Cos[ψ], r Sin[ϕ] == R Sin[ψ]} /. ψ -> 2 ArcTan[uψ] //TrigExpand

soluψ = Solve[eqn, {R, uψ}];
solψ = soluψ /. uψ -> Tan[ψ/2]
(*{{R -> -r Sqrt[a^2 Cos[ϕ]^2 + Sin[ϕ]^2],
Tan[ψ/2] ->a Cot[ϕ] -Csc[ϕ] Sqrt[a^2 Cos[ϕ]^2 +Sin[ϕ]^2]}
, 
{R ->r Sqrt[a^2 Cos[ϕ]^2 + Sin[ϕ]^2],
Tan[ψ/2] ->Csc[ϕ] (a Cos[ϕ] + Sqrt[a^2 Cos[ϕ]^2 +Sin[ϕ]^2])}}*)
```

Knowing

```
Tan[x] == (2 Tan[x/2])/(1 - Tan[x/2]^2) // FullSimplify (*True*)
```

we get

```
tanψ = (2 Tan[ ψ/2])/(1 - Tan[ ψ/2]^2) /. solψ// FullSimplify
(* {-(Tan[ϕ]/a), -(Tan[ϕ]/a)}*)
```

Hope it helps!